# Jquery Datepicker staying visible after selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using JQuery UI's datepicker to show a date.

I have a webpage with a table that allows the user to edit a date by clicking the "edit" button. Through javascript the text turns into an `input type="text"` and then is set to a `datepicker` when I focus on the input.

This all appears to work perfectly, but then when I select the date, the value doesn't change and the calendar stays visible and does not disappear.

This is what it looks like prior to me hitting the "Edit" button...

[image]

Then when I hit the "Edit" button....

[image]

And finally I click on the date field, the calendar pops up, I select a different date, and the calendar does not go away!

[image]

Here is the code for when the user clicks on the edit button...

```
        function editGeneralCheckIn(id)
        {
          var savedate = document.getElementById("adate_"+id);
          var t = savedate.innerHTML.split(/[- :]/);

          var datecol = document.getElementById("date_"+id);
          datecol.innerHTML = "";
          datecol.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" name=\"date_"+id+"\" value=\""+t[1]+"/"+t[2]+"/"+t[0]+"\" onfocus=\"loadUpDate("+id+")\">";
          datecol.innerHTML += "<input type=\"text\" name=\"time_"+id+"\" value=\""+t[3]+":"+t[4]+":"+t[5]+"\">";
          datecol.innerHTML += "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\""+id+"\">";

          var controll = document.getElementById("controlbuttons_"+id);
          controll.innerHTML = "<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"generalCancel("+id+")\">Cancel</button>";
          controll.innerHTML += "<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"generalOkay("+id+")\">Okay</button>";

        }
```

The highlight is to look at what happens on the onfocus of the new input...

```
        function loadUpDate(id)
        {      
          $('#date_'+id).datepicker();
        }
```

Here is the code in my `<head>` section, although the calendar appears just fine, so I don't believe it is a library issue... I think it might have something to do with a value already being in the box maybe?

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/customerhistory.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libraries/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="libraries/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  </head>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see in document of Datepicker have option `autoclose`

you can try it:

```
$('#date_'+id).datepicker({
    autoclose: true
});
```

http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#autoclose

Comment: That did not work. Same results. Thank you for that suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I had a DIV and an INPUT with the same ID. Thank you.

Comment: also, I didn't have an id attribute, and was using the name attribute. Rookie mistake.